# TabView showing multiple back buttons when there are more than 5 tab items

Tags: swiftui

When there are more than 5 tab views, SwiftUI automatically generates a 'More' button.

However, this created unwanted behavior like the following:

[image]

Here is the sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            NavigationView{
                Text("1")
                    .navigationTitle("1")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Text("1")
            }
            NavigationView{
                Text("2")
                    .navigationTitle("2")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Text("2")
            }
            NavigationView{
                Text("3")
                    .navigationTitle("3")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Text("3")
            }
            NavigationView{
                Text("4")
                    .navigationTitle("4")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Text("4")
            }
            NavigationView{
                Text("5")
                    .navigationTitle("5")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Text("5")
            }
            NavigationView{
                Section{
                    Form{
                        Picker("Value", selection: $value){
                            Text("1").tag("1")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("6")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Text("6")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Instead of showing just < 6, it shows also < More.

Why is this happening and how do I make it show only < 6?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59005618/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Not really... I wanted to keep the 'More' button. I think it's great. My only requirement is to get rid of the second < back button.

Comment: Apple uses NavigationView for standard More, so you need to get rid of some navigation view to avoid duplication.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the 'Edit' option where it allows you to rearrange tabItem won't work anymore? As the ones that are displayed by default should be wrapped within NavigationView.

Comment: @Josh, do you have an answer to this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

... follow up on comments,

if you want to use standard More button then only way to avoid double navigation bars is to use only one external(!) `NavigationView`, then `TabView` uses its navigation bar for `More` button, ie.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {    // << only here !!
        TabView{
//            NavigationView{       // << not here !!
        Text("1")
// there are other topics about syncing navigation title
//          .navigationTitle("1")
            .tabItem{
                Text("1")
            }
```